# как сделать правильно замыкание функцией на api lua c++

Tags: api, lua

помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно замыкание функцией на api lua c++, не получается.

```
    void checkerror(lua_State *L, const char* LUA) {
    if (luaL_dostring(L, LUA) != LUA_OK) {
        cout << "error " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << endl;
    }
    }
void showstack(lua_State *L) {
    int i = lua_gettop(L);/* получаем количество элементов в стеке.*/
    cout << "\n  the number on the stack = " << i - 1 << "\n\n\n";
    int j = (i) * -1;
    i = -1;
    for (i; i > j; i--) {
        int t = lua_type(L, i);
        cout << "\t " << i << "  ";
        if (LUA_TSTRING == t) {
            cout << lua_tostring(L, i) << endl;
        }
        if (LUA_TNUMBER == t) {
            double x = lua_tonumber(L, i);
            int x2 = (int)x;
            if (x == x2) { cout << x2 << endl; }
            else { cout << x << endl; }
        }
        if (LUA_TBOOLEAN == t) {
            cout << lua_toboolean(L, i) << endl;
        }
    }
   }
     //showstack(L);// вывести стек. 
   static int counter(lua_State *L) {
    int val = lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    lua_pushinteger(L, ++val);  /* new value */
    lua_copy(L, -1, lua_upvalueindex(1));  /* update upvalue */
    return 1;  /* return new value */
}

int newcounter(lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushinteger(L, 0);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &counter, 1);
    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char* LUA = R"(
 c1 = newcounter()
      print(c1(), c1(), c1())   --> 1    2    3
      c2 = newcounter()
      print(c2(), c2(), c1())   --> 1    2    4

        )";

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();/*Функция создает новое Lua состояние. Она вызывает lua_newstate с функцией-*/
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    checkerror(L, LUA);//Функция проверка на ошибки.

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
    lua_getglobal(L, "newcounter");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, newcounter);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, counter, 1);
    lua_setglobal(L, "newcounter");
    lua_settable(L, -3);
    lua_close(L);

    cin.get();//ожидает ввода символа программа завершается.
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот как сделал замыкание, может кому поможет.

```
    void checkerror(lua_State *L, const char* LUA) {
    if (luaL_dostring(L, LUA) != LUA_OK) {
        cout << "error " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << endl;
    }
}
static int newcounter(lua_State *L) {
    int val = lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    lua_pushinteger(L, ++val);          /*  новое   значение    */
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);   /*  дублирует   его */
    lua_replace(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));    /*  обновляет   верхнее значение*/
    return 1;
}
static int counter(lua_State *L) {
    lua_pushinteger(L, 0);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, newcounter, 1);
    return 1;  /* return new value */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char* LUA = R"(
   c1 = counter()
   print(c1(), c1(), c1())   --> 1    2    3 
   )";

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();/*Функция создает новое Lua состояние. Она вызывает lua_newstate с функцией-*/
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_register(L,"counter", counter);// отправить c функцию в стек.
    checkerror(L, LUA);

    lua_pushcclosure(L, newcounter, 1);

    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);// вызвать функцию foo.

    lua_close(L);

    cin.get();//ожидает ввода символа программа завершается.
    return 0;
}
```